# Install a topshelf windows service from c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, topshelf

has anyone installed a topshel windows service. I'm able to install/uninstall it using the command prompt and  everything works great but i was wondering if i could possibly install it programatically using c# or vb.net. thanks in advance

Comment: You could simply call the the command prompt via the Shell

Comment: There is no API for installing/uninstalling a topshelf service. We just use batch files for those jobs.

Comment: how can i run a batch file as an admin, i found this online but did not work

Comment: var processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = "invoicerelease.exe install";
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: Hursey do you have an example using shell?

Comment: the running the command, it must be as an adming for it to work. thanks in advance